# Variable "" has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!" GraphQl error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to save groupChatName as the value of the TextInput and save that name on the backend but in doing so I am getting the error "Possible unhandled promise, data: null, variable 'groupChatName' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String'", path: null.

`` export const createGroupChat = `mutation createGroupChat($groupChatName:String! $messages:String $createdUser:String! $users:String) {
  createGroupChat(input:{
    groupChatName:$groupChatName
    messages:$messages
    createdUser:$createdUser
    users:$users
  }){
    groupChatName
    messages
    createdUser
    users
  }
}`; ``

````
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('');
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [groupChatName, setGroupChatName] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(currentUser => setCurrentUser(currentUser)) 
    .catch (() => setUsername(null));
    }, []);

  GroupChat = () => {
    if (value.length > 0) {
      setValue('')
      setGroupChatName('')
      props.navigation.navigate('Message', { value });
    }
  };

  GroupChatMutation = async () => {
    const GroupChatDetails = { groupChatName, currentUser };
    const newGroupChat = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createGroupChat, { GroupChatDetails }));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newGroupChat));

  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Create GroupChat Name</Text> 
            <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                    <TextInput 
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            multiline={true}
                            placeholder={'Type in a GroupChatName'}
                            placeholderTextColor="#abbabb"
                            value={value}
                            onChangeText={value => setValue(value)}
                            onChange={value => setGroupChatName(value)}



                    />
.......```
````